# log4j doesn't see log4j.properties file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm trying to configure logging in my app where log4j.properties is put to /resources folder an has the following content:

```
#log level
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, file
log4j 
# 
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\agent\temp\panel log.log
#
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
#
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

and on my app start I see the following in the console:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

what does this mean and how to fix it?

Comment: Add /resources folder to the CLASSPATH

Comment: it is in the classpath

Comment: I'm sure you think it is, but the JVM says you're wrong.  Check it again until you see what you've missed.  Put that file in the WEB-INF/classes directory of your deployment and it'll work.

Comment: i've changed log4j.properties to log4j.xml and put it to resources folder and now everything is correct. maybe my log4j version doesn't supprot .properties format

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the log4j.properties in the root of your source folder. Or alternatively add resources to your classpath.

The root problem is log4j not seeing your config file, so you need to make it accessible.

Extract from log4j manual:

> Default Initialization under Tomcat
>
> The default log4j initialization is particularly useful in web-server
>   environments. Under Tomcat 3.x and 4.x, you should place the
>   log4j.properties under the WEB-INF/classes directory of your
>   web-applications. Log4j will find the properties file and initialize
>   itself. This is easy to do and it works.
>
> You can also choose to set the system property log4j.configuration
>   before starting Tomcat. For Tomcat 3.x The TOMCAT_OPTS environment
>   variable is used to set command line options. For Tomcat 4.0, set the
>   CATALINA_OPTS environment variable instead of TOMCAT_OPTS.

Comment: putting it to the root of my source folder takes no effect

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I was using tomcat 7.
I solved the problem by adding conf path to the /bin/setenv.sh (if you are on linux, create the file if it does not exist) like this:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dconfig.location=file -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/lib/log4j.properties"
```

if you are on windows edit or create setenv.bat and write something like this (not sure about the path format):

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS%-Dconfig.location=file -Dlog4j.configuration=file://c:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/lib/log4j.properties
```

Forgot to say: this will affect all the apps on the server

Comment: This is incorrect and a bad idea.  You won't have any such option if you deploy your code to a server that's not your local machine.  Better to learn how to do it properly.

Comment: It may not be the best solution, but it works in my case. Yes, I forgot to mention that the server is dedicated to my single application and I have full control on it.
The proper solution, placing the file in the single application folder, did not take effect, but I have to say that I had to run tomcat with mule libs installed, so maybe the reason I had to do the ugly way is this. Unfortunately I was running out of time and could not dedicate any further investigation to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i've changed log4j.properties to log4j.xml and put it to resources folder and now everything is correct. maybe my log4j version doesn't supprot .properties format